# SceneKit: retrieving material ID from imported Collada file

Tags: swift

i have several Collada files with material IDs attached to different sets of polygons on the asset which I would like to retrieve  by code using SceneKit.

Is this possible? I have tried looking for answers using google but it seems a lot is just a tutorial on using SceneKit. Perhaps my search keys aren't optimal but I only have the following which goes as close to the topic:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14584/properly-export-collada-for-use-in-scenekit

Any help greatly appreciated

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the `SceneKit Editor` to verify that the Collada/DAE export was successful.

Select the model, click on the `Scene Graph View` (at the bottom left), traverse to the node and then look it up in the `Materials Inspector` (one of the inspectors at the top right).  If you can find it here, then programmatically it should be available as a `SCNMaterial`.